# Trying to return a result from mongodb to node, but am getting an unexpected object back

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im trying to return a result from mongodb when I run

```
> db.message.find({})
```

from the mongo command line I get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e48d8586a704e8f3cec81e"), "message" : "this is a message from mongo" }
```

As expected.

Now in my router in node.js I have this code:

```
var router = function () {
    indexRouter.route('/')
        .get(function(req, res){
        var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/message';
        mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            var collection = db.collection('message');
            collection.find({}, 
                function (err, results) {
                    res.render('index', {
                        message : results
                    })
                    console.log(results);
                });
        });
    });

    return indexRouter;
}
```

This runs fine however my results are a confusing object that I have not seen before the object starts like this:

```
Readable {
  pool: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler: 
   { s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: {},
  ns: 'message.message',
  cmd:
```

I have gotten results from mongo like this before and have compared this code with my known working code. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a problem with searching my db for anything when I am expecting just one result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I need to use .toArray as my db could have multiple results. heres the router code that works:

```
var router = function () {
    indexRouter.route('/')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/message';
            mongodb.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                var collection = db.collection('message');
                collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, results) {
                    res.render('index', {
                        message: results
                    });
                    console.log(results);
                });
            });
        });

    return indexRouter;
}
```